# Help solving the diophantine word problem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A farmer purchased $100$ head of livestock for a total cost of $\$4000$. Prices were as follow: calves $\$120$ each, lambs $\$50$ each, piglets $\$25$ each. If the farmer obtained at least one animal of each type, how many did he buy?

total number of livestock$=100$,

number of calves$=x$,

number of lambs$=y$,

number of piglets$=z$,

cost of a calf$-120$,

cost of a lamb$-50$,

cost of a piglet$-25$

equations:
1) $x+y+z=100$
2) $120x+50y+25z=4000$
  $24x+10y+5z=800$

$24x+10y+5(100-x-y)=800$
$19x+5y=300$

What do I do from here to find the solution? I don't know mods yet..

Comment: The correct equations are $c + l + p = 100$ and $120c + 50l + 25p = 4000$.

Comment: ok, makes sense. Do I solve them separately or find a way to combine the two equations? Sorry I'm very new to this

Comment: also how do I solve the equations with 3 variables. Do I still try to find the gcd between 120, 50, 25 and 4000?

Comment: You'll necessarily have to solve them both simultaneously, otherwise you're dropping critical information from the problem.

Comment: ok, how do I combine the two equations to solve them simultaneously?

Comment: Truth is, the only way you're going to be able to solve this with the information given is guess and check. You're either missing an equation, since 3 variables have to have 3 equations to solve for, or someone really wants you to waste time on this. :p

Comment: @JoshTullos 3 variables in 2 equations is indeterminate when you allow all real values, but the restriction to integers allows you to solve the problem uniquely.

Answer (score 2):

The answer - I believe it's unique, but it's very late and I'm tired - is $15$ cows, $3$ lambs, and $82$ piglets.

This was my approach.

First, you have a system of two linear equations. The usual thing to do is to try to eliminate some of the variables. Multiply the first equation by $120$ to get $120c+120l+120p=12000$, and subtract the other equation from that to eliminate $c$, leaving $70l+95p=8000$. Dividing by the GCD, we get $14l+19p=1600$, and now we can set up a linear relation between $p$ and $l$:

$$p=\frac{1600-14l}{19}$$

I chose to divide by $19$ and not $14$ because $19$ happens to be prime. This is a good thing because we're now going to work modulo $19$ to determine when the right hand side is an integer. We want $1600-14l\equiv0\mod19$, and since $19$ is prime we get to do division, and find that the only possibility is $l\equiv3$. So:

$$l=19k + 3$$

And, applying the previous relation for $p$ and simplifying:

$$p=14k+82$$

Great, we've expressed $l$ and $p$ in terms of one variable $k$ - we now have a system of two equations in *two* variables. Plug what we've found back into the original two equations and we get:

$$\begin{align}
33k+85+c&=100\\
1300k+2200+120c&=4000
\end{align}$$

From which we deduce the solution I gave above.

Comment: 25 cows at 120 = 3000. 3 lambs at 50 = 150. 82 piglets at 25 = 2050. 3000 + 150 + 2050 = 5200. Something wrong with your math there.

Comment: Also, can't believe I missed this... but 25+3+82? You're at 110 animals, not 100 animals... You must have been really tired...

Comment: @JoshTullos Not quite an error in the math, just made a mistake when typing up my notes. It's actually $15$ cows, not $25$. Thanks!